wsl2 unable to resolve host names behind vpn
I connect to a VPN to be able to access our company hosts. Everything works fine on windows. However the hosts behind the VPN are not visible on wsl2.
I've tried adding the VPN address to /etc/resolv.conf but it didn't help.
As a workaround I've manually added the host-IP mappings to /etc/hosts and it works so it's a name resolution issue.
What do I need to do to get the WSL2 to correctly resolve all the host names without having to manually add them to /etc/hosts?
My /etc/resolv.conf:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 172.23.10.128 (Windows VPN address)
Windows version: Windows 10
Ubuntu version: Linux USC-W-45RM4Y3-A 5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Jan 11 04:09:03 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Please have a clearly defined question and details such as what version of Ubuntu you are using.

Added more details
